# Pymongo update a document with a condition

Tags: conditional-statements, pymongo, document

I'm trying to update a document under a condition with pymongo, but failed to figure out a way. Use this document as an example:

```
{"_id":"mol001",
"deid":["a001", "a003", "a005"],
"count":3}
```

For _id of mol001, I'm trying to append a tag to deid and update count to 4:

```
{"_id":"mol001",
"deid":["a001", "a003", "a005", "b001"],
"count":4}
```

One thing needs to be aware of is the count value. if It's larger than 10, the document will not be updated. Below is what I came up with:

```
    mol = "mol001"
    b001 = "b001"
    try: 
        ## in case mol001 doesn't exist, use upset = True
        count = coll.find_one({"_id": mol}, {"_id": False, "count": 1})['count']
    except:
        count = 0
    if count <= 10:
        coll.update_one({"_id": mol}, {'$push': {'deid': b001}}, upsert=True)
        coll.update_one({"_id": mol}, {"$inc": {"count": 1}}, upsert=True)
```

This was very inefficient since it needs to do one query and update twice. Is there a way to  use $cond to do the update in one sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "mol001",
  "count": {
    "$lte": 10
  }
},
{
  "$push": {
    "deid": "b001"
  },
  "$inc": {
    "count": 1
  }
},
{
  "upsert": true
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DDGd8myurzh).

Comment: Great, thanks. That's exactly what I need. Below is what can work in python: ``` 
try: 
 collection.update({
   "_id": "mol001",
   "count": {
     "$lte": 10
   }
 },
 {
   "$push": {
     "deid": "b001"
   },
   "$inc": {
     "count": 1
   }
 },
 
   upsert=True
 ) 
except:
 pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two operations into a single update operation:

```
coll.update_one({'_id': mol}, {'$push': {'deid': b001}, '$inc': {'count': 1}}, upsert=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful to reduce one operation. I haven't found any example to use $cond in pymongo. Do you know if pymongo support conditional syntax?